# IceFaces 3.3: ace:dialog not working with IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, icefaces

I'm using IceFace 3.3.0 with MyFaces. I have a problem with ace:dialog. It's not working on IE 7 or 8, it works fine with any other browser.

Here's a simple example that shows the problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xml:lang="de" lang="de" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:icecore="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/core"
  xmlns:ace="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/components"
  xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component"
>
<h:head>
  <title></title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
<ace:dialog id="helpDialog" header="Help" widgetVar="helpDialog"
  closable="true" modal="true" draggable="false" showEffect="clip"
  hideEffect="fade" closeOnEscape="true" width="400" height="600">
  <h:outputText value="Help Dialog" />
</ace:dialog>

<h:form id="myform">
  <ace:panel id="mypanel" header="Test" closable="false" toggleable="false">
    <h:commandLink immediate="true" value="&gt; Dialog" onclick="helpDialog.show();" />
  </ace:panel>
</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

On IE8, this code will not show the dialog and produces a JavaScript error when loading the page:

```
SCRIPT438 object doesn't support this property or method
```

The JavaScript error appears on this generated line:

```
helpDialog = ice.ace.create("Dialog",["helpDialog_main",{"isVisible":false,"minHeight":0,"width":400,"height":600,"draggable":false,"modal":true,"show":"clip","hide":"fade","title":"Help","ariaEnabled":true}])
```

I already tried different versions of MyFaces and even Mojarra, so I think this is an icefaces issue.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The dialog must be enclosed in a form or even the content can be enclosed by form as shown in the link.

```
<h:form>
  <ace:dialog id="helpDialog" header="Help" widgetVar="helpDialog"
    closable="true" modal="true" draggable="false" showEffect="clip"
    hideEffect="fade" closeOnEscape="true" width="400" height="600">
    <h:outputText value="Help Dialog" />
  </ace:dialog>
</h:form>
```

For more information, [Ace Dialog](http://www.icesoft.org/wiki/display/ice/dialog)

Comment: Unfortunately this solution is not working for me. Is there any other method that you know of ?